# ASP.NET core pipeline: are components added to the processing pipeline visible somewhere?

Tags: asp.net-core

As components are added to the processing ASP.NET core pipeline are these visible in some collection accessible from the WebApplication object?

Comment: Yes, in ASP.NET Core, you can access the list of components that are added to the processing pipeline through the ApplicationBuilder object. Each middleware component that you add to the pipeline is represented by a delegate that implements the RequestDelegate class. These delegates are stored in a collection within the ApplicationBuilder object, and they are executed in the order in which they were added. You can access this collection of middleware delegates through the ApplicationBuilder object's ApplicationServices property.

Comment: I've seen that the IApplicationBuilder interface exposes the ApplicationServices property but looking thru its private properties I don't seem to find anything that looks like the stack of middleware components. Are you able to provide more details?